# Working with multiple spreadsheets

Tags: excel

I've downloaded several csv files from the uk metropolitan police that have the same data format. Each file represents 1 month, I've downloaded 5 years worth of files so 60 files in total.

There are 2 important columns that I want to process before getting to work on it.

1) the type of crime column, I'm only interested in burglaries. How to get only the burglaries from all 60 files?

2) sum of burglaries that happen within a LSOA. There is a column with the LSOA name. How to get a table made out of all the tables from 1) that looks like the following:

> LSOA/Month | April 2012 | May 2012 | June 2012 | ....
>
> Barking01A |  count here
>
> Barking01B |
>
> Lewisham01A

How to do this?

EDIT: Police data link here https://data.police.uk/data/

Comment: @RyanVincent edited the OP

Comment: thanks for that - looks useful :)